# Getting a value from a nested template in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So basically I have something like this in my home page

```
<template>
  <div id="body">
    <sideBar :menu="menu" :tableName='tableName' titleOfPage='titleOfPage'></sideBar>
    <div id="menu">
      HOME PAGE
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

In the sidebar template you can select your page. It will forward you this template

```
<template>
  <div id="body">
    <sideBar :menu="menu" :tableName='tableName' :titleOfPage='titleOfPage'></sideBar>
    <div id="main">
      <h1>{{ titleOfPage }}</h1>
    ....
```

I need the sidebar template to set the `titleOfPage` as it corresponds to the page clicked. I tried different ways but didn't manage. I appreciate the help by explaining me how to solve this issue.

Comment: Look into [Vue router](https://router.vuejs.org/).

Comment: I have. I made a function that calls `this.$router.push` and in the `params` object passed the new `titleOfPage` but then if the user bedsides to go back the changes are gone

Comment: Are you using vuex in your application?

Answer (score 0):

The [Vue docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode) recommend not using `$router` directly but instead configuring `props` to pass to the routed components:

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/', redirect: '/page-a', component: { template: `<router-view></router-view>` }, name: 'Home' },
  { path: '/page-a', component: Page, props: { titleOfPage: 'Page A' }},
  { path: '/page-b', component: Page, props: { titleOfPage: 'Page B' }},
];
```

If your props are dynamic and depend on the current route, you can pass a function to the `props` property of each route configuration:

```
{ path: '...', component: ..., props: (route) => ({ query: route.query.q }) }
```

To solve your issue, you can simply create a page component which receives the props from the router and render your `sidebar` component in its template:

```
<!-- template for page component -->
<template>
  <div id="body">
    <sideBar :menu="menu" :tableName='tableName' :titleOfPage='titleOfPage'></sideBar>
    <div id="main">
      <h1>{{ titleOfPage }}</h1>
      <!-- ... -->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

---

**DEMO:** [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-mjeuqi?file=app.js)